# How should missing information in relational databases be modeled properly?

Tags: database, database-design, null, relational-database

[Some](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/Missing-info-without-nulls.pdf) argue that `NULL`s in relational databases are evil and propose alternative approaches to missing information, usually leading to relations in 6NF. Then, essentially, missing information is being expressed by missing tuples in relations. However, in my understanding, that violates the Closed World Assumption, because if a tuple can possibly appear in some relation but doesn't, that means that the proposition corresponding to that tuple is false, *which is different from being unknown*.

For example, consider following relation:

```
|---------------|
| NAME   | AGE  |
|--------+------|
| andrey | 30   |
|---------------|
```

Here, the predicate is "the person called `NAME` is `AGE` years old", so we know that Andrey is 30 years old. If we do not know his age, then we could express that with a `NULL`:

```
|---------------|
| NAME   | AGE  |
|--------+------|
| andrey | NULL |
|---------------|
```

However, if `NULL`s are prohibited, we could not do that. Instead, we could remove the tuple in the relation with `NAME` andrey. But under the Closed World Assumption, that would imply that andrey does not have any age at all (maybe he is eternal), which is different from saying that andrey *does* have some age, which we simply do not know.

So, my question is: is it really possible to model missing information correctly without `NULL`s and not violating the Closed World Assumption? Or do I miss something?

Comment: You are making a mistake if you think that the semantics of NULL are the same as that of an unknown value - i.e. that null *means* unknown. Null means no such thing. If you wish to assert that a value is unknown then you can of course do so as values (not nulls) in a relation e.g. the relation: AGE_IS_UNKNOWN {Name}

Comment: @sqlvogel OK, `AGE_IS_UNKNOWN { Name }` makes sense. But if `NULL` does not mean "unknown", what _does_ it mean?

Comment: Actually came up with the answer myself: simply change the predicate from "The person called NAME is AGE years old" to "The age of person called NAME **is known _and_ is equal to AGE**". Then, the negation of the predicate becomes "The age of the person called NAME **is unknown _or_ the person does  not have a valid age** (maybe he is eternal or yet to be born)", which is fine.

Comment: The intended "meaning" of null depends on what variety of null you are talking about. There is no general agreement or single consistent definition of what nulls are for. ISO Standard SQL for example does not define any specific meaning or purpose of nulls. In maths and in everyday reality if X is an unknown value then X=X is a TRUE statement. That's not the case if X is null in SQL, so SQL-style nulls evidently do not mean the same as unknown in any real or precise sense. In practice nulls get used by database designers to represent (inaccurately) a whole range of different meanings.

Comment: @sqlvogel Good point. Thanks.